# How can i enable zoom and scroll in devexpress webchart control?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I'm use the devexpress webchart control in asp.net and this html code:

```
<dxchartsui:WebChartControl ID="WebChartControl1" runat="server" CrosshairEnabled="True"  AppearanceNameSerializable="Dark" PaletteName="Red Violet" style="text-align: center" Height="435px" Width="900px" EnableCallbackAnimation="True">
        </dxchartsui:WebChartControl>
```

but i want enable zoom and scroll that control,i read this tutorial:
[ENABLE ZOOM AND SCROLL](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11234)

but i can not understand how can i enable that,how can i solve that?thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the documentation you have the link for is for the Windows Forms control, not the webchartcontrol.